# NGINX - Reverse proxy 404 - The requested resource is not found

Tags: nginx

I have a windows IIS server with a working site: http://bla.example.com/something/login

I set a nginx reverse proxy. The idea is to access via: pass.example.com

Here's the config:

```
upstream pass {
server bla.example.com weight=100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=5;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name pass.example.com;

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
location / {
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
access_log /var/log/nginx/pass.example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/pass.example.com.error.log error;
}
}

server { 
listen       443 ssl;
server_name pass.example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!kEDH;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
access_log /var/log/nginx/pass.example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/pass.example.com.error.log error;
location / {
         proxy_pass http://pass/;
         proxy_redirect     off;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

Please, any idea?.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Is that an assignment? IIS can take good care of those, and why nginx?